# pandas sort column by ABSOLUTE correlation to first column

Tags: python, database, pandas, correlation

Assume columns names `A, B, C, etc..`

Obviously, sorting by correlation would be:
    `ix = df.corr().sort_values('A', ascending=False).index`
    `df_sorted = df.loc[:, ix]`

What If I wanted to sort by absolute correlation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ix = abs(df.corr()).sort_values('A', ascending=False).index
```

This was so much easier than expected.